# How to select multiple picture from private document directory folder not from photo gallery in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to i phone programming.Can any body tell me that how to select multiple pictures form private document directory folder.I got some code like ELCImagePickercontroller by using this i can able to select form photo gallery images but i want to select images form private document folder.Can any body tell me that how can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have fatch image from Document directory and Create `Viewcontroller` using `ScrollVIew` like `photoGallary` right.? then May be you added each image in `UIButton` for getting Particular image Tag. if you do this stuff like my above logic then you can select Multiple Image like bellow points.

- you have to creat Anoter IBAction with Button Tag with identify `isSelected` or not if is not then when Select you can set other ImageView Transparant Layor on UIButton with same size and set CheckImage
- Then you can also add particular selected imagePath From Document Directory and add each select imagePath in one `NSMutableArray`
- then you can do your logic and stuff with this created selectedImageMutaleArray show, delete whatever you want

Hope my above logic and info its helps you :)

Comment: hai thanks for giving replay,is it possible to select multiple pictures form private document directory

Comment: yes i have already tald you logic of it how to select multiple image from document directory.

Comment: i had used Fgallery project for displaying private document directory images.here all images i stored in array after that by using fgallery iam displaying images in viewcontroller in like photo gallery

Comment: i am never working on fgallery friend but i just working manual create imageGallary from Document directly as same as your stuff and i giving logic of it as my answer how to do this stuff.